# Cyberduck not SFTPing to Rpi

Tags: ssh

I am accessing my Rpi with SFTP cyberduck through its IP addres but after formatting the Rpi and reinstalling PI, I get the a failed connection:

"Exhausted available authentication methods. Contact your hosting company."

But it's just my Pi I'd like to access! I have no hosting company. I've tried reinstalling Cyberduck but the issue persists.

Cyberduck works fine in Windows. Also I can ssh from mac terminal and also from PuTTy

Any idea of what I can do to connect to my Pi from my mac again?

Cheers,
/Ivan

Comment: Have you turned on logging and reviewed the contents?

 Cyberduck (for MAC users)
To enable the logging for Cyberduck select the View menu and click on the "Toggle Log Drawer" option. This will open a panel at the bottom of the application. Once you reconnect, you will be able to see the log for your FTP connection displayed in it.

Comment: I could choose  click on the "Toggle Log Drawer" option, so I proceeded to updated the program, and now it's working. Thanks :-)